# is there any way to create a javascript function like element.function(options)?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JavaScript function that works like,

```
element.mycustomfunction(options);
```

I know how to do this with jquery but I don't know how to do this with pure JavaScript.

Here is what I have did in my code.

```
var elm = document.getElementById('someid');
```

I want do this,

```
elm.mycustomfunction(options_object);
```

I have tried,

```
(function(){
      HTMLElement.prototype.mycustomfunction = function(options){
            console.log( options );
      }
})();
```

but it doesn't console anything. Is there something what I'm missing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add your jQuery code here

Comment: By `element` do you mean a html element? or just some object?

Comment: What specifically is `element` in this case? Do you want the function available on just that one object or all objects of whatever type it is?

Comment: By element I mean html element like 'document.getElementById('someid')'

Comment: There is a way to do it but said way is probably not something you want to do.

Comment: @Phil by element is only one element.

Comment: For just that one object, you can simply add the function, eg `element.myfunction = function(options) { ... }`

Comment: @Phil I've edited my question

Comment: Well, `getElemenetById` is incorrect for starters. It should be `getElementById`

Comment: sorry for typo mistake but it's already getElementById in my code

Comment: Works fine over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/eajyg9q6/

Comment: It's work fine in jsfiddle, however I got null element in getElementById. I just put getElementById in document.onreadystatechagne.... and now it's working fine. Thanks @Phil